# postgresqlのテーブル間にある共通idの出力

Tags: sql, postgresql

PostgreSQLです。
同じ構造のテーブルtable1~table5があり、idがそれぞれにあります。
1つでもダブっているものをSQLであぶりだしたいのですが、

```
select id
from table1
intersect
select id
from table2
intersect
...
```

のように書くと、おそらくすべてのテーブルに存在しているidのみが抽出されるという認識です。
table2とtable5のみに存在している、table2,3,5に存在しているのようなidも抽出したいのですが、
どのようなクエリを書けばよろしいでしょうか。
出来たら番号1〜5の入っている列bangoも反映させたいです。
詳しい方、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

他のテーブルに同じIDが存在するものを抽出するSQLの例です。
【SQL】

```
SELECT id FROM (
    SELECT id, 'table1' AS tablename FROM  table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, 'table2' AS tablename FROM  table2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, 'table3' AS tablename FROM  table3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, 'table4' AS tablename FROM  table4
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, 'table5' AS tablename FROM  table5
) AS XX GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(id) > 1;
```

table2とtable5で1が重複しており、
table2とtable3とtable5で2が重複しているケースで実行してみました。

【動作確認のSQL】

```
WITH
table1 AS (
    SELECT 10 id
),
table2 AS (
    SELECT 1 id UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 id UNION ALL
    SELECT 20 id
),
table3 AS (
    SELECT 2 id UNION ALL
    SELECT 30 id
),
table4 AS (
    SELECT 40 id
),
table5 AS (
    SELECT 1 id UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 id UNION ALL
    SELECT 50 id
)
SELECT id FROM (
    SELECT id, 'table1' AS tablename FROM  table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, 'table2' AS tablename FROM  table2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, 'table3' AS tablename FROM  table3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, 'table4' AS tablename FROM  table4
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, 'table5' AS tablename FROM  table5
) AS XX GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

【動作確認結果】

```
 id
----
  1
  2
(2 rows)
```